# How do I create an =IF(OR()) statement which will count the number of true/false conditional values?

Tags: excel, if-statement, ms-office

My Uncle is asking me to help his police department fix their excel sheet. They track call codes in an excel sheet which looks like this:

[image: this].

Rows in the top image are individual calls which are categorized by the numbers in A-B-C 40+ (Radio Signals, bottom image) based on the subject of the call. In my example I've placed 3 call signals from row 46 in Radio Signals as well as row 49. Now what I'd like to see happen is a count of 3 in both E46 and E49.

The issue I'm having is a limited knowledge of programming Excel statements. I know there are IF statements I can use in conjunction with AND and OR statements but this seems very long and tedious. Based on the current setup of this document, could I use a more efficient method to gain a count of signals belonging to this cell?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using the COUNTIFS statement works well. The following formula worked like a charm for counting occurrences of multiple conditions over a range of cells.

**For Cell 46-E**

```
=COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=37")+COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=56")+COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=64")+COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=65")+COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=70")+COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=81")+COUNTIFS(A7:A39,"=91")
```

Comment: I recommend Peter Albert's approach but if you are "hardcoding" the numbers into the formula you can shorten your COUNTIFS version with `=SUM(COUNTIFS(A7:A39,{37,56,64,65,70,81,91}))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of calls is in Sheet1 column A and the comma separated list is in Sheet2, place the following formula in Sheet2:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Sheet1!$A$:$A$&","," "&Sheet2!A46&",")))
```

Make sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering the formula!

Comment: +1.....but I'd suggest one "improvement" - you can use ISNUMBER instead of NOT(ISERROR

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I've done the edit. Good to know that ISNUMBER can handle errors. Now that I think about it, it makes sense to have the IS... function be able to handle errors. :-)